# Jenkins integration with Soap UI Open source

Tags: jenkins, soapui

Our organization needs to integrate Jenkins with Soap UI tests.

I read that we can integrate Jenkins by providing the TestRunner.bat file path into Jenkins build.

But we need to do it with the free version of SoapUI and Jenkins.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes its poosible. Jenkins is able to integrate all kinds of processes

Comment: You mean it does not require any type of paid license? @StimpsonCat

Comment: I am not sure about the license. But you can use it with jenkins. I think you need to buy a license for SopaUI pro. Btw. why soap UI?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to integrate the SoapUI (open source edition) project execution from Jenkins.

SoapUI has command line interface to execute the tests. testrunner.bat(.sh) utility of SOAPUI_HOME/bin directory can execute the SoapUI project.

Jenkins build step can execute commands, so you can call `$SOAPUI_HOME/bin/testrunner.sh` along with different [options](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

- Create your Jenkins job, there will be an "**Build**" category,
- Under "**Execute windows batch command**" sub-category.

  **Enter you testrunner.bat commands, e.g.:**

  ```
  testrunner.bat -s"Your TestSuite Name" -r -j -f"result path" -I %NGPProject% -PParameterA=%Atrribute% -PServicesParametersDataPath="./" -PServicesEndpoint=%ServicesEndpoint% -PServicesCompareEndpoint=%CompareEndoint%
  ```

  you can add "-PParameterName" to add many parameters you want to input.
  PS: find details here https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-functional-tests.html.
  [image]
- Have your Source Code Management (Git , SVN...)

[image]

*Above should be the simple way to cope with your question. Also you can use ant or maven project, I am not so familiar with ant/maven, so it's just the idea hope can help you.*